# Separating arrow separated values in data frame to separate unequal columns using R?

Tags: r, csv, strsplit

I have a data frame with following sample values.

```
[1] "entry.cei"                                                                               
[2] "entry.lifecycle->hist.open.personal demand chequing account->exit.lifecycle->entry.cei"  
[3] "entry.lifecycle->hist.open.personal demand savings account->exit.lifecycle->entry.cei"   
[4] "entry.transaction->txn.no source available->exit.transaction->entry.cei"                 
[5] "entry.branch->exit.branch->entry.transaction->txn.in-branch->exit.transaction->entry.cei"
```

I need to split them by "->" put them in different columns, say V1, V2 etc.
For example:

```
           V1                             V2               V3             V4           V5     V6    V7
1   entry.cei   
2   entry.lifecycle hist.open.personal demand chequing account  exit.lifecycle  entry.cei   
3   entry.lifecycle hist.open.personal demand savings account   exit.lifecycle  entry.cei
```

How can I achieve this in R?
I tried to used rbind with strsplit() but I think it requies equal number of columns.

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer.  `read.csv` is much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use `gsub` to replace the `->` with a comma, then use `read.csv`.  If you have commas in the data, then just use `>` instead of a comma and it should be fine.

```
read.csv(text = gsub("->", ",", x, fixed = TRUE), header = FALSE)
#                  V1                                         V2                V3            V4               V5        V6
# 1         entry.cei                                                                                                      
# 2   entry.lifecycle hist.open.personal demand chequing account    exit.lifecycle     entry.cei                           
# 3   entry.lifecycle  hist.open.personal demand savings account    exit.lifecycle     entry.cei                           
# 4 entry.transaction                    txn.no source available  exit.transaction     entry.cei                           
# 5      entry.branch                                exit.branch entry.transaction txn.in-branch exit.transaction entry.cei
```

Or alternatively

```
read.table(text = gsub("->", ",", x, fixed = TRUE), sep = ",", fill = TRUE)
```

You can also still use `rbind` and  `strsplit` as long as you make all the list elements the same length first. The `length<-` replacement function can help with that.

```
s <- strsplit(x, "->", fixed = TRUE)
data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(s, `length<-`, max(sapply(s, length)))))
#                  X1                                         X2                X3            X4               X5        X6
# 1         entry.cei                                       <NA>              <NA>          <NA>             <NA>      <NA>
# 2   entry.lifecycle hist.open.personal demand chequing account    exit.lifecycle     entry.cei             <NA>      <NA>
# 3   entry.lifecycle  hist.open.personal demand savings account    exit.lifecycle     entry.cei             <NA>      <NA>
# 4 entry.transaction                    txn.no source available  exit.transaction     entry.cei             <NA>      <NA>
# 5      entry.branch                                exit.branch entry.transaction txn.in-branch exit.transaction entry.cei
```

where the original `x` vector is

```
x <- c("entry.cei", 
 "entry.lifecycle->hist.open.personal demand chequing account->exit.lifecycle->entry.cei", 
 "entry.lifecycle->hist.open.personal demand savings account->exit.lifecycle->entry.cei", 
 "entry.transaction->txn.no source available->exit.transaction->entry.cei", 
 "entry.branch->exit.branch->entry.transaction->txn.in-branch->exit.transaction->entry.cei")
```